Piping yt_dlp to FFMPEG using python: ffmpeg failing to recognize video data from pipe
I am trying to pipe the output of yt_dlp into a pipe used by ffmpeg which then outputs.:
def pipe_function(url):

ydl_command = [
    'yt-dlp', '-f', 'bestvideo+bestaudio', '--quiet', '--no-warnings', '-o', '-', url
]


ffmpeg_command = [
    'ffmpeg', '-v', 'debug', '-i', '-', '-c', 'copy', 'output.mp4'
]


# Start yt-dlp process
ydl_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ydl_command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)


# Start ffmpeg process and pipe output from yt-dlp to ffmpeg
ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(
    ffmpeg_command,
    stdin=ydl_process.stdout,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)



ydl_stdout, ydl_stderr = ydl_process.communicate()


try:
    print(ydl_stdout[:100].decode('utf-8'))
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print(ydl_stdout[:100].decode('latin-1', errors='ignore'))

ffmpeg_stdout, ffmpeg_stderr = ffmpeg_process.communicate()


if ydl_stderr:
    try:
        print("error in yt-dlp: ", ydl_stderr.decode('utf-8'))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print("decode error in yt-dlp: ", ydl_stderr)

if ffmpeg_stderr:
    try:
        print("error in ffmpeg: ", ffmpeg_stderr.decode('utf-8'))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print("decode error in ffmpeg: ", ffmpeg_stderr)


try:
    print(ffmpeg_stdout[:100].decode('utf-8'))
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print(ffmpeg_stdout[:100].decode('latin-1', errors='ignore'))

return ffmpeg_stdout

This outputs an audio file. If I look at the console I see some messages. I have removed the lengthier stuff and shown only what I find the most interesting:
[mpegts @ 0000021b8576a380] probing stream 0 pp:1457
[mpegts @ 0000021b8576a380] probed stream 0
[mpegts @ 0000021b8576a380] parser not found for codec bin_data, packets or times may be invalid.
For transform of length 120, inverse, mdct_float, flags: [aligned, out_of_place], found 6 matches:
    1: mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: [16, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 544
    2: mdct_pfa_15xM_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [30, ∞], factors[2]: [15, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 304
    3: mdct_pfa_5xM_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [10, ∞], factors[2]: [5, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 144
    4: mdct_pfa_3xM_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [6, ∞], factors[2]: [3, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 112
    5: mdct_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 96
    6: mdct_naive_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: -130976
For transform of length 60, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 1 matches:
    1: fft_pfa_15xM_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: [60, ∞], factors[2]: [15, 2], flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 688
For transform of length 4, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 1 matches:
    1: fft4_fwd_asm_float_sse2 - type: fft_float, len: 4, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 352
Transform tree:
    mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: 120, factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only]
        fft_pfa_15xM_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: 60, factors[2]: [15, 2], flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
            fft4_fwd_asm_float_sse2 - type: fft_float, len: 4, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
For transform of length 128, inverse, mdct_float, flags: [aligned, out_of_place], found 3 matches:
    1: mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: [16, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 544
    2: mdct_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 96
    3: mdct_naive_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: -130976
For transform of length 64, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 3 matches:
    1: fft_sr_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 480
    2: fft_sr_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 448
    3: fft_sr_asm_float_avx - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 416
Transform tree:
    mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: 128, factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only]
        fft_sr_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: 64, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
For transform of length 480, inverse, mdct_float, flags: [aligned, out_of_place], found 6 matches:
    1: mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: [16, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 544
    2: mdct_pfa_15xM_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [30, ∞], factors[2]: [15, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 304
    3: mdct_pfa_5xM_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [10, ∞], factors[2]: [5, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 144
    4: mdct_pfa_3xM_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [6, ∞], factors[2]: [3, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 112
    5: mdct_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 96
    6: mdct_naive_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: -130976
For transform of length 240, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 1 matches:
    1: fft_pfa_15xM_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: [60, ∞], factors[2]: [15, 2], flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 688
For transform of length 16, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 2 matches:
    1: fft16_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: 16, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 512
    2: fft16_asm_float_avx - type: fft_float, len: 16, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 480
Transform tree:
    mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: 480, factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only]
        fft_pfa_15xM_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: 240, factors[2]: [15, 2], flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
            fft16_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: 16, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
For transform of length 512, inverse, mdct_float, flags: [aligned, out_of_place], found 3 matches:
    1: mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: [16, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 544
    2: mdct_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 96
    3: mdct_naive_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: -130976
For transform of length 256, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 3 matches:
    1: fft_sr_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 480
    2: fft_sr_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 448
    3: fft_sr_asm_float_avx - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 416
Transform tree:
    mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: 512, factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only]
        fft_sr_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: 256, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
For transform of length 960, inverse, mdct_float, flags: [aligned, out_of_place], found 6 matches:
    1: mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: [16, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 544
    2: mdct_pfa_15xM_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [30, ∞], factors[2]: [15, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 304
    3: mdct_pfa_5xM_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [10, ∞], factors[2]: [5, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 144
    4: mdct_pfa_3xM_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [6, ∞], factors[2]: [3, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 112
    5: mdct_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 96
    6: mdct_naive_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: -130976
For transform of length 480, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 1 matches:
    1: fft_pfa_15xM_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: [60, ∞], factors[2]: [15, 2], flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 688
For transform of length 32, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 2 matches:
    1: fft32_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: 32, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 512
    2: fft32_asm_float_avx - type: fft_float, len: 32, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 480
Transform tree:
    mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: 960, factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only]
        fft_pfa_15xM_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: 480, factors[2]: [15, 2], flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
            fft32_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: 32, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
For transform of length 1024, inverse, mdct_float, flags: [aligned, out_of_place], found 3 matches:
    1: mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: [16, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 544
    2: mdct_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 96
    3: mdct_naive_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: -130976
For transform of length 512, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 3 matches:
    1: fft_sr_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 480
    2: fft_sr_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 448
    3: fft_sr_asm_float_avx - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 416
Transform tree:
    mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: 1024, factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only]
        fft_sr_asm_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: 512, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
For transform of length 1024, forward, mdct_float, flags: [aligned, out_of_place], found 2 matches:
    1: mdct_fwd_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, fwd_only], prio: 96
    2: mdct_naive_fwd_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, fwd_only], prio: -130976
For transform of length 512, forward, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf], found 5 matches:
    1: fft_sr_ns_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf], prio: 480
    2: fft_sr_ns_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf], prio: 448
    3: fft_sr_ns_float_avx - type: fft_float, len: [64, 131072], factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf], prio: 416
    4: fft_pfa_ns_float_c - type: fft_float, len: [6, ∞], factors[2]: [7, 5, 3, 2, any], flags: [unaligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf], prio: 112
    5: fft512_ns_float_c - type: fft_float, len: 512, factor: 2, flags: [unaligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf], prio: 96
Transform tree:
    mdct_fwd_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: 1024, factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, fwd_only]
        fft_sr_ns_float_avx2 - type: fft_float, len: 512, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf]
For transform of length 64, inverse, mdct_float, flags: [aligned, out_of_place], found 3 matches:
    1: mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: [16, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 544
    2: mdct_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 96
    3: mdct_naive_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: -130976
For transform of length 32, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 2 matches:
    1: fft32_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: 32, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 512
    2: fft32_asm_float_avx - type: fft_float, len: 32, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 480
Transform tree:
    mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: 64, factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only]
        fft32_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: 32, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
For transform of length 64, inverse, mdct_float, flags: [aligned, out_of_place], found 3 matches:
    1: mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: [16, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 544
    2: mdct_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: 96
    3: mdct_naive_inv_float_c - type: mdct_float, len: [2, ∞], factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [unaligned, out_of_place, inv_only], prio: -130976
For transform of length 32, inverse, fft_float, flags: [aligned, inplace, preshuf, asm_call], found 2 matches:
    1: fft32_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: 32, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 512
    2: fft32_asm_float_avx - type: fft_float, len: 32, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call], prio: 480
Transform tree:
    mdct_inv_float_avx2 - type: mdct_float, len: 64, factors[2]: [2, any], flags: [aligned, out_of_place, inv_only]
        fft32_asm_float_fma3 - type: fft_float, len: 32, factor: 2, flags: [aligned, inplace, out_of_place, preshuf, asm_call]
[mpegts @ 0000021b8576a380] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5005000 microseconds st:0
[mpegts @ 0000021b8576a380] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 5403308 bytes read:5404624 seeks:0 frames:365
Input #0, mpegts, from 'fd:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 130 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100], 152, 1/90000: Data: bin_data ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 0/1
  Stream #0:1[0x101](und), 213, 1/90000: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url output.mp4.
Applying option c (codec name) with argument copy.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: output.mp4.
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] No explicit maps, mapping streams automatically...
[aost#0:0/copy @ 0000021b89b8d800] Created audio stream from input stream 0:1
[file @ 0000021b89586680] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Successfully opened the file.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.20.100
  Stream #0:0(und), 0, 1/44100: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Starting thread...
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] Starting thread...
Automatically inserted bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc'; args=''
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] EOF while reading inputpeed=  40x
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] Terminating thread with return code 0 (success)
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] All streams finished
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Terminating thread with return code 0 (success)
[AVIOContext @ 0000021b87146340] Statistics: 2723207 bytes written, 2 seeks, 14 writeouts
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Output file #0 (output.mp4):
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Output stream #0:0 (audio): 7232 packets muxed (2737451 bytes);
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Total: 7232 packets (2737451 bytes) muxed
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] video:0kB audio:2673kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
size=    2659kB time=00:02:47.92 bitrate= 129.7kbits/s speed=41.3x
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.20.100
  Stream #0:0(und), 0, 1/44100: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Starting thread...
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] Starting thread...
Automatically inserted bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc'; args=''
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] EOF while reading inputpeed=  40x
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] Terminating thread with return code 0 (success)
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] All streams finished
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Terminating thread with return code 0 (success)
[AVIOContext @ 0000021b87146340] Statistics: 2723207 bytes written, 2 seeks, 14 writeouts
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Output file #0 (output.mp4):
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Output stream #0:0 (audio): 7232 packets muxed (2737451 bytes);
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Total: 7232 packets (2737451 bytes) muxed
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] video:0kB audio:2673kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
size=    2659kB time=00:02:47.92 bitrate= 129.7kbits/s speed=41.3x
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] Starting thread...
Automatically inserted bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc'; args=''
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] EOF while reading inputpeed=  40x
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] Terminating thread with return code 0 (success)
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] All streams finished
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Terminating thread with return code 0 (success)
[AVIOContext @ 0000021b87146340] Statistics: 2723207 bytes written, 2 seeks, 14 writeouts
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Output file #0 (output.mp4):
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Output stream #0:0 (audio): 7232 packets muxed (2737451 bytes);
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Total: 7232 packets (2737451 bytes) muxed
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] video:0kB audio:2673kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
size=    2659kB time=00:02:47.92 bitrate= 129.7kbits/s speed=41.3x
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] All streams finished
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Terminating thread with return code 0 (success)
[AVIOContext @ 0000021b87146340] Statistics: 2723207 bytes written, 2 seeks, 14 writeouts
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Output file #0 (output.mp4):
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Output stream #0:0 (audio): 7232 packets muxed (2737451 bytes);
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Total: 7232 packets (2737451 bytes) muxed
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] video:0kB audio:2673kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
size=    2659kB time=00:02:47.92 bitrate= 129.7kbits/s speed=41.3x
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] Output file #0 (output.mp4):
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Output stream #0:0 (audio): 7232 packets muxed (2737451 bytes);
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Total: 7232 packets (2737451 bytes) muxed
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] video:0kB audio:2673kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
size=    2659kB time=00:02:47.92 bitrate= 129.7kbits/s speed=41.3x
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0]   Total: 7232 packets (2737451 bytes) muxed
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] video:0kB audio:2673kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
size=    2659kB time=00:02:47.92 bitrate= 129.7kbits/s speed=41.3x
[out#0/mp4 @ 0000021b89b251c0] video:0kB audio:2673kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
size=    2659kB time=00:02:47.92 bitrate= 129.7kbits/s speed=41.3x
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] Input file #0 (fd:):
size=    2659kB time=00:02:47.92 bitrate= 129.7kbits/s speed=41.3x
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] Input file #0 (fd:):
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080] Input file #0 (fd:):
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080]   Input stream #0:1 (audio): 7232 packets read (2737451 bytes);
[in#0/mpegts @ 0000021b85724080]   Total: 7232 packets (2737451 bytes) demuxed
[AVIOContext @ 0000021b85744880] Statistics: 27226912 bytes read, 0 seeks

It seems to me that the video data is being interpreted as bin_data and no codec is found for it. What is going on here?
Must YT_DLP data be converted to some other format before being read by FFMPEG?
Thank you.

Can you share a sample of the created file?
